# Flutter app freezes when loading Markers on iOS

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my app I need to load a large amount of Markers in a Google Map from one list when I click a FAB. On android everything works fine, on iOS my app freezes when I assign all the Markers, then after a few seconds, loads all the markers and keeps working fine.

The two Sets:

```
  // MARKERS
  Set<Marker> allMarkers = {}; // STORES ALL THE MARKERS
  RxSet<Marker> shownMarkers = <Marker>{}.obs; // STORES ONLY MARKERS NEAR THE USER
```

The button that loads all Markers:

```
FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
              onPressed: () {
                // dialogs.loadingDialog(
                //     context, loadingContext, 'Caricando tutti i bidoni...');
                final state = _key.currentState;
                if (state != null) state.toggle();
                Get.back();
                setState(() {
                  isShowingAllMarkers = true;
                  isMenuButtonVisible = false;
                });
                locationManager.zoomToUser(
                    14, initialCoords, googleMapController);

                shownMarkers.value = allMarkers; // THE LIST ASSIGNMENT

                addUserMarker(shownMarkers, initialCoords);
                
                sub!.pause();

              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.map),
            ),
```